# Write an equation for a rational function with:

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Write an equation for a rational function with:

Vertical asymptotes at $x = -5$ and $x = 5$

$x$ intercepts at $x = -2$ and $x = -6$

Horizontal asymptote at $y = 6$

$y =$ ?

I have $$\frac{(x+2)(x+6)}{(x+5)(x-5)}$$

I know the horizontal asymptote is the division of the highest degree of numerator and denominator. How do I find what it is? $\frac{12x^2}{2x^2} = 6$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not just try $f(x)=\frac{6(x+2)(x+6)}{(x+5)(x-5)}$ ?